# If a power of a matrix has trivial kernel, then so does the matrix itself

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose that $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. Show that if $A^4x=0$ has only the trivial solution, then $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution.

I know this is proved the invertible matrix theorem but I have no idea how to even begin.

Comment: This doesn't need any theorems whatsoever (except associativity of multiplication).

Answer (score 4):

If $Ax=0$, then $A^4x=A^3(Ax)=A^3(0)=0$, so $x=0$.

Comment: I believe that the OP asks the question in exactly the opposite sense.

Comment: Seriously, I did not get your point. How did you conclude that $x=0$?

Comment: Nishant clearly points out that if x satisfies Ax = 0, then $A^4x = 0$ as well. But since $A^4x = 0$ has only a trivial solution, so Ax = 0 must have a trivial solution as well!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $Ax=0\implies A^n x=0\ \forall n\ge 1\implies \mathcal{N}(A)\subset \mathcal{N}(A^n)\ \forall n\ge 1$. Since we have here $\mathcal{N}(A^4)=\{0\}\implies \{0\}\subset \mathcal{N}(A)\subset \{0\}\implies \mathcal{N}(A)=\{0\}$.

Comment: I think it should be $\subseteq$ instead of $\subset$.

Comment: $\subset $ is a standard notation to indicate subset unless otherwise specified.

Comment: As far as my understanding concerns there is a difference between 'subset' and 'proper subset' (and also between their notations).

Comment: @Rajada, of course there is a difference between *subset* and *proper subset* but what I tried to mean is that $\subset$ is used as a standard notation for subset in many places. Of course it is perfectly fine and maybe better to use $\subseteq$ in place of $\subset$ but in many places one uses $\subset$ to mean *just* subset (proper or improper) and $\subsetneq$ for proper subset. See this [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset) article to dissolve the confusion.

Comment: whatever nice proof